# AWS Athena Error: INTERNAL_ERROR_QUERY_ENGINE on CREATE TABLE

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm trying to execute the following query on AWS Athena:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS salesforce_processed."case"
WITH (
    format = 'JSON',
    external_location = 's3://path/to/my/bucket/',
    partitioned_by = ARRAY['dt_obs']
)
AS
SELECT
    nullif(trim("case".id), '') AS "id" , 
    try(cast(date_parse("case".dt_obs, '%Y-%m-%d') as date)) as "dt_obs"
FROM salesforce_raw."case" as "case"
```

But it returns this error message: *[ErrorCode: INTERNAL_ERROR_QUERY_ENGINE] Amazon Athena experienced an internal error while executing this query. Please contact AWS support for further assistance. You will not be charged for this query. We apologize for the inconvenience.*

There's no other error info, and if I execute the select statement alone, it runs with success.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem on Athena engine version 2. The `try()` function was the culprit in my query. My query previously ran on the v1 engine, so I suspect the upgrade to v2 is to blame.

The only solution I found was to rewrite the query to avoid `try()`.

Comment: Yes, the word "case" was the problem on my query. The solution was to use escape characters (`).

Doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this a few times recently. So far I have these causes:

- The bucket does not exist (or not with the sufficient permissions)
- The above cause - avoid using keywords
- Earlier tables without partitions discovered (!)